Is there a compatibility issue in NextJS 14.1.0 Dependencies with Shadcn-ui latest version
I am expecting to see shadcn-ui function cn() to call in all the classes that I have passed into the function. What is see is this:
enter image description here
I ve tried to relocate the utils folder and ui/cn. It returns the compiling issues and errors. I am working on the local settings as well, there is no error in there:
enter image description here
Here is the package.json:
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev --port 3000 --hostname 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start --port 3000 --hostname 0.0.0.0",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.9.0",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.18.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-accordion": "^1.2.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-alert-dialog": "^1.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-aspect-ratio": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-avatar": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-checkbox": "^1.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-collapsible": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-context-menu": "^2.2.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-hover-card": "^1.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-menubar": "^1.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu": "^1.2.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-popover": "^1.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-progress": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-radio-group": "^1.2.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-scroll-area": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-select": "^2.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-slider": "^1.2.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-switch": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-tabs": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-toast": "^1.2.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-toggle": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-toggle-group": "^1.1.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-tooltip": "^1.1.2",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "cmdk": "^1.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^3.6.0",
    "embla-carousel-react": "^8.2.0",
    "init": "^0.1.2",
    "input-otp": "^1.2.4",
    "lucide-react": "^0.427.0",
    "mongodb": "^6.8.0",
    "next": "^14.1.0",
    "next-themes": "^0.3.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.40",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-day-picker": "^8.10.1",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.53.0",
    "react-resizable-panels": "^2.1.1",
    "recharts": "^2.12.7",
    "sonner": "^1.5.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.5.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.9",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "vaul": "^0.9.1",
    "zod": "^3.23.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.14.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.2.5",
    "prisma": "^5.18.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.5.4"
  },
  "description": "Welcome to the NextJS base template using the `create-next-app`. This template supports TypeScript, but you can use normal JavaScript as well.",
  "main": "next.config.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}

This is the page.tsx code:
import React from "react";
import {
  Card,
  CardHeader,
  CardTitle,
  CardDescription,
  CardContent,
  CardFooter,
} from "../../@/components/ui/card";
import { cn } from "../../@/lib/utils";
import db from "../../app/db/db";

async function getSalesData() {
  const data = await db.order.aggregate({
    _sum: { price: true },
  });
}

export default function AdminDashboard() {
  return (
    <div className={cn("grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4")}>
      <DashboardCard
        title="Sales"
        description="This is the card desctipiton..."
        content="This is the card content."
        footer="This is the footer."
      />
      <DashboardCard
        title="Orders"
        description="This is the card desctipiton..."
        content="This is the card content."
        footer="This is the footer."
      />
      <DashboardCard
        title="Payments"
        description="This is the card desctipiton..."
        content="This is the card content."
        footer="This is the footer."
      />
      <DashboardCard
        title="Customers"
        description="This is the card desctipiton..."
        content="This is the card content."
        footer="This is the footer."
      />
    </div>
  );
}

type DashboardCardProps = {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  content: string;
  footer: string;
};

function DashboardCard({
  title,
  description,
  content,
  footer,
}: DashboardCardProps) {
  return (
    <Card>
      <CardHeader>
        <CardTitle>{title}</CardTitle>
        <CardDescription>{description}</CardDescription>
      </CardHeader>
      <CardContent>{content}</CardContent>
      <CardFooter>{footer}</CardFooter>
    </Card>
  );
}

my layout or index file code is:
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";
import { Nav, NavLink } from "../components/Nav";
import { cn } from "../../utils/cn";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"], variable: "--font-sans" });

export default function AdminLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{ children: ReactNode }>) {
  return (
    <>
      <Nav>
        <NavLink href="/admin">Dashboard</NavLink>
        <NavLink href="/admin/products">Products</NavLink>
        <NavLink href="/admin/users">Customers</NavLink>
        <NavLink href="/admin/orders">Orders</NavLink>
      </Nav>
      <div className={cn("container my-6", inter.variable)}>{children}</div>
    </>
  );
}

I am expecting to see shadcn-ui function cn() to call in all the classes that I have passed into the function. What is see is this:

I've tried to relocate the utils folder and ui/cn. It returns the compiling issues and errors. I am working on the local settings as well, there is no error in there:


Please specify the version you are asking about. "Latest version" will change when a new version is released.
